# How can i apply my python logic into the tkinter GUI? It's a simple GET request program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that sends sms texts. My only issue is that i cant make it do stuff with tkinter. Sorry if it sounds confusing, english is not my first language and ill try to explain my best.

This is a simple GET request to send a SMS text through my API:

```py
# GET
import requests
to = input("Enter Receiver: ") 
fromm = input("Enter Sender: ") 
message = input("Enter Message: ") 


payload = {'to': to, 'from': fromm, 'message': message, 'email': '@example.com', 'api_secret': '123456789abcdefg'}
r = requests.get('https://example.com/dashboard/api',params=payload)

print(r.text)
```

Once this Get request is sent we get a json response confirming that the message was sent.

This is what my GUI with tkinter looks like:

```py
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
Sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# Buttons
send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)


app.title('SMS')
app.geometry('430x145')

#start
app.mainloop()
```

It took me about two hours to learn how to make the GUI, but as of right now i'm simply lost. I have no actual idea on how to implement the logic into the GUI.
How do i make the text & buttons work? Where do i add the functions?
I'm literally lost.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from a guide or tutorial about tkinter more than anything else.

Comment: Simply replace `to = input(...)` by `to = Receiver_text.get()` (apply to `from` and `message` as well).  Put the modified code inside `send_message()` function.

Comment: I tried but i failed. :(

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hey, thank you! I managed to apply the first step but i'm not sure how to put the modified code inside the send_message(). My syntaxt is really really awful

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the logic (replace all `input()` by `xxx.get()`) into the function `send_message()`:

```py
import requests

def send_message():
    receiver = Receiver_text.get()
    sender = Sender_text.get()
    message = Message_text.get()

    payload = {'to': receiver, 'from': sender, 'message': message, 
               'email': '@example.com', 'api_secret': '123456789abcdefg'}
    r = requests.get('https://example.com/dashboard/api', params=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference you GUI let's give your code a little bit more structure, so it is more visible what is happening.
I have put the setup of the window in a function `my_window` passing it the argument `app` from `main`. Pressing the button `send` the values of `sender_text`, `receiver_text` and `message_text` are obtained by using `sender_text.get()`, `receiver_text.get()`, etc.. The results of these are passed to the function `send_message` through a `lambda` function.

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Label, Entry, Button, W


def send_message(snd_txt, rcv_txt, msg_txt):
    print(f'sent: {snd_txt}, {rcv_txt}, {msg_txt}')


def clear_text():
    print('cleared')


def my_window(app):

    # Sender
    sender_text = StringVar()
    sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
    sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=sender_text)
    sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    # Receiver
    receiver_text = StringVar()
    receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
    receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
    receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=receiver_text)
    receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)

    # Message
    message_text = StringVar()
    message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
    message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=message_text)
    message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # Buttons
    send_btn = Button(
        app, text='Send', width=12,
        command=lambda: send_message(sender_text.get(), receiver_text.get(), message_text.get()))
    send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
    clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
    clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)


def main():
    app = Tk()
    app.title('SMS')
    app.geometry('430x145')
    my_window(app)
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, it is more common to define `my_window` as a `class` and make the functions `clear_text` and `send_message` methods of this `class` which gives a lot more flexibility.

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Label, Entry, Button, W


class my_window:

    def __init__(self, app):
        # Sender
        self.sender_text = StringVar()
        sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
        sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=self.sender_text)
        sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # Receiver
        self.receiver_text = StringVar()
        receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
        receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=self.receiver_text)
        receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)

        # Message
        self.message_text = StringVar()
        message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
        message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=self.message_text)
        message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Buttons
        send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=self.send_message)
        send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
        clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=self.clear_text)
        clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def send_message(self):
        print(f'sent: {self.sender_text.get()}, '
              f'{self.receiver_text.get()}, '
              f'{self.message_text.get()}')

    def clear_text(self):
        self.sender_text.set('')
        self.receiver_text.set('')
        self.message_text.set('')
        print('cleared')


def main():
    app = Tk()
    app.title('SMS')
    app.geometry('430x145')
    my_window(app)
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```